# Testing of method which takes long time to execute

Tags: java

Let's say I have method like this:

```
public int toTest() {
    try { Thread.sleep(60 * 1_000); }
    catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    return 8;
}
```

And I would like to test it e.g. check if returned value is correct, like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int actual = toTest();
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(8);
}
```

Is there any way to "simulate" time lapse so during test execution I will not be force to wait for whole minute?

Edit:
Probably I described my question too concrete. I didn't want to focus on this exact one minute but on way to bypass it. There could be even 100 days but my question is if there is method to simulate this time lapse.

Like in project reactor methods with are using virtual time https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/snapshot/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html#withVirtualTime-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: You could lower the values?

Comment: No, that would not be a unit then. Your unit is this method exactly, and test will take however much time the unit takes (plus assertions, ofc). If you don't want the sleep, take this method apart and test only the non-sleeping part.

Comment: An integral part of testing a method like this would include checking if the 60 seconds of proposed sleep do sleep for actually 60 seconds... so speeding that up would do the opposite of creating a good test imho.

Comment: I disagree. A strength of unit tests is the ability to simulate/fake/mock values that affect the behavior of a unit. Time is just another value

Comment: Maybe my question was too concrete. This one minute was just example, there could be 1 second or 10 days. Purpose of question was to find out if I could somehow bypass this time.

Comment: Then the delay should be a parameter that could be changed from outside. A unit test must never mock the unit under test, but only its environment. The way it is implemented, the 60 seconds are part of the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Powermock.

```
// This will mock sleep method
PowerMock.mockStatic(Thread.class, methods(Thread.class, "sleep"));

PowerMockito.doThrow(new InterruptedException()).when(Thread.class);
Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
```

At the start of class, you will need to add this

```
@PrepareForTest(YourClassToWhich_ToTest_MethodBelong.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit test the method as is (unless you add mocking..) if you want you can test internal method as `toTestInternal`:

```
public int toTest() {
    try { Thread.sleep(60 * 1_000); }
    catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    return toTestInternal();
}

public int toTestInternal() {
return 8;
}
```

and test the method you want (`toTestInternal`):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int actual = toTestInternal();
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make the interval a dynamic parameter. It will save your time:

```
public int toTest(int interval) {
  try { 
      Thread.sleep(interval); 
   }catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

  return 8;
}
```

and the test class to be like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int actual = toTest(60);
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(8);
}
```